# Dart: How to define an abstract class for Model Objects which has a function that takes it's own type as a parameter

Tags: dart, abstract-class

i have the following Problem in Dart:

i want to define an abstract class ModelObjects which has some functions. Among them is the function isSame

```
abstract class ModelObject{
   bool isSame(ModelObject object);
   ...
}
```

Now I'm defining the class PlayerModel as follows:

```
class PlayerModel extends ModelObject{
     bool isSame(PlayerModel player){
       //some code that checks if the objects are the same
     }
```

which leads dart to give me a compiling error:

PlayerModel.isSame' ('bool Function(PlayerModel)') isn't a valid override of 'ModelObject.isSame' ('bool Function(ModelObject)').dart(invalid_override)

I've managed to sidestep this issue by making ModelObjects a generic

```
abstract class ModelObject<T>{
    bool isSame(T object);}
```

But this seems to be more a cheat than a solution.

Now my question is: Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem or are abstract classes simply the wrong approach in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you can use the [`covariant`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#the-covariant-keyword) keyword:

```dart
class PlayerModel extends ModelObject {
  @override
  bool isSame(covariant PlayerModel player) {
    //some code that checks if the objects are the same
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! This brought me to this page: [link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems), where the problem is explained very well.
Also i adapted your answer to put the covariance keyword into the superclass ModelObject:
abstract class Modelobject{ bool isSame(covariant ModelObject){...} }
which seems to work as well.